# c# Parse HTML with AngleSharp, find DIV with part of ID

Tags: c#, html, anglesharp

I just try the following for findng all div's in HTML with known Part of the ID:

```
var AllDiv = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "div" && m.GetAttribute("id").StartsWith("new_order_"));
```

It allways results in an NullReferenceException.
I also try it with "Contrains", but with the same result.

The div's look like:

```
<div id="new_order_50000_US">...</div>
<div id="new_order_4000_EU">...</div>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

THX

Comment: Haven't used AngleSharp but CsQuery, is like jQuery for C#, This is what i'm using on my most HTML Parsing projects.

Comment: Also have you checked the examples of AngleSharp? They are pretty well documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to check if current `div` has `id` attribute before checking the attribute value to avoid NRE :

```
var AllDiv = document.All.Where(m => m.LocalName == "div" && 
                                     m.HasAttribute("id") && 
                                     m.GetAttribute("id").StartsWith("new_order_"));
```

Comment: That's it. Sometimes it's that simle, if you know it.